# Want to reply to answers and comments on my previous question but don't know how

Tags: discussion

I asked this question two days ago, “Preparing a 19th Century Printed Engraving for Halftone Printing Today. I ‘Descreened’ in Photoshop. Thoughts?”, and would like to follow up with how I used the suggestions. But I don’t see a “Reply” button. What ought I to do?

Comment: You can also add comments below either your question or under the answers. The user who has posted the answer will automatically get notified. If you want to comment on someone else's comments you can add *@username* and they will get a notification. You should *upvote* answers you like and *accept* the best answer you think answers your question.

Answer (score 5):

StackExchange Sites (such as this one) are unlike "forums".

Stack sites are about direct answers to direct questions as opposed to threaded discussions. There's no "reply" button anywhere due to this.

You can click the **add a comment** link which appears under every answer to supply additional information regarding that answer if you'd like.

- For example.. you can click the "add a comment" link below this answer to add a comment.

Comment: I can't add my reply as a comment as you suggest because it allows too few characters. Also, I wanted to add my resultant image and I doubt it will all me to do that in here, either.

Comment: You can always edit the question @WillS -- but again, this site isn't really about *discussions*. If an answer works for you, merely tick the green checkmark nest to it to select it as the correct answer. There's generally little need to show the result of any answer.

Comment: @WillS You can add links to comments which would allow you to add images and also fix your minimum length issue

Comment: @WillS If you want to add an image to a comment, you can upload to imgur, and include the link in the comment.